# What is the meaning of this anomaly warning message?

Tags: database-design, schema

I have run an analysis with SchemaSpy.

The tool gave me a warning message for two tables. The warning message is:

> Tables with incrementing column names, potentially indicating denormalization

What is meaning of the above error?

For reference :

http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/anomalies.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the [sample table](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/tables/address.html) in your link, I'd suggest it's taking issue with fields such as:

```
phone1
phone2
```

or

```
notes1
notes2
notes3
```

This may indicate a design flaw (but not always), and if so, one that can probably be corrected by more descriptive field names or perhaps a child table.

For example, someone might have more than one phone number... what if someone has three? Seven? Maybe data like this should be in a subtable, and perhaps even with some sort of indicator of what *type* of phone number it is, whether it's a preferred phone number, etc. Alternatively, maybe just renaming the fields to `phone_home` and `phone_cell` will be enough to eliminate confusion and allow you to collect all of the data you need.

Comment: Specifically looks as though it takes that as an indicator the table may not be in [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) then.

Comment: I often see this sort of thing with tables that have fields such for address lines: `addressLine1, addressLine2, addressLine3`.

Comment: It works.. Thanks... Wonder.. How decision making engine considering micro things which we even didn't care...